# Docker Container Networking with Docker-in-Docker

Tags: networking, docker, docker-in-docker

I would like to network with a child docker container from a parent docker container, with a docker-in-docker setup.

Let's say I'm trying to connect to a simple Apache httpd server. When I run the httpd container on my host machine, everything works fine:

```
asnyder:~$ docker run -d -p 8080:80 httpd:alpine
asnyder:~$ curl localhost:8080
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

But when I do the same from a docker-in-docker setup, I get a `Connection refused` error:

```
asnyder:~$ docker run -d --name mydind --privileged docker:dind
asnyder:~$ docker run -it --link mydind:docker docker:latest sh
/ # docker run -d -p 8080:80 httpd:alpine
/ # curl localhost:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

I have tried a couple alterations without luck. Specifying the `0.0.0.0` interface:

```
asnyder:~$ docker run -d --name mydind --privileged docker:dind
asnyder:~$ docker run -it --link mydind:docker docker:latest sh
/ # docker run -d -p 0.0.0.0:8080:80 httpd:alpine
/ # curl 0.0.0.0:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8080: Connection refused
```

Using the host network:

```
asnyder:~$ docker run -d --name mydind --privileged docker:dind
asnyder:~$ docker run -it --link mydind:docker docker:latest sh
/ # docker run -d --network host httpd:alpine
/ # curl localhost:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

Surprisingly, I was unable to find any existing articles on this. Does anyone here have some insight?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me first ask you if you are sure you want a docker-in-docker setup? Read [this](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) blog post first.

Comment: @JonesV I avoided getting into the specific scenario in the question to keep it general, but since you asked...

I'm writing a [GitLab CI Pipeline Job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/). Jobs in GitLab CI run inside a docker container that you can specify. I'm writing a Job that produces a PDF report based on some HTML, and I want to take advantage of an existing Docker image to do this. So, I have a docker-in-docker situation.

I hope this helps clarify :)

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help with the docker-in-docker setup. I just wanted to make sure your were aware of the points mentioned in the blog post =).

Comment: I had this exact same issue myself – GitLab CI using a `docker` image with a `docker:dind` service, and I also could connect from my own host, but not within the `docker` container. Very clear and well-posed question!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are pros and cons for both DinD and bind mounting the Docker socket and there are certainly use cases for both. As an example, check out [this set of blog posts](https://applatix.com/case-docker-docker-kubernetes-part/), which does a good job of explaining one of the use cases.

Given your example docker-in-docker setup above, you can access Apache httpd server in one of two ways:

1) From inside the `docker:dind` container, it will be available on `localhost:8080`.

2) From inside the `docker:latest` container, where you were trying to access it originally, it will be available on whatever hostname is set for the `docker:dind` container. In this case, you used `--name mydind`, therefore `curl mydind:8080` would give you the standard Apache `<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>`.

Hope it makes sense!

Comment: Both you guys are awesome! Thx!

Comment: What would cause the child container to not be accessible from the host container, e.g. localhost:8080 Failed to connect, connection refused (`curl`)?

Comment: This is a good description of the issue I see when trying to access the child container on an exposed port from the host container: https://www.edureka.co/community/12457/docker-container-networking-with-docker-in-docker

Comment: I am still struggling with this. is the link or a network needed between the parent and the dind contaner?

Answer (score 13):

Building upon [Yuriy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44996703/1666398):

> 2) From inside the `docker:latest container`, [...] it will be available on whatever hostname is set for the `docker:dind` container. In this case, you used `--name mydind`, therefore `curl mydind:8080` [...]

In the Gitlab CI config, you can [address the DinD container by the name of its image](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services) (in addition to the name of its container, which is auto-generated):

> ## Accessing the services
>
> ---
>
> Let’s say that you need a Wordpress instance to test some API integration with your application.
>
> You can then use for example the [tutum/wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/r/tutum/wordpress/) image in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`:
>
> ```
> services:
> - tutum/wordpress:latest
> ```
>
> If you don’t [specify a service alias](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#available-settings-for-services), when the job is run, `tutum/wordpress` will be  started and you will have access to it from your build container under two hostnames to choose from:
>
> - `tutum-wordpress`
> - `tutum__wordpress`

Using

```
service:
- docker:dind
```

will allow you to access that container as `docker:8080`:

```
  script:
  - docker run -d -p 8080:80 httpd:alpine
  - curl docker:8080
```

---

**Edit**: If you'd prefer a more explicit host name, you can, [as the documentation states](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#available-settings-for-services), use an `alias`:

```
services:
- name: docker:dind
  alias: dind-service
```

and then

```
  script:
  - docker run -d -p 8080:80 httpd:alpine
  - curl dind-service:8080
```

Hth,
dtk

Comment: What happens if in GitlabCI I use this script: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up` and if I have a service called `mongodb` ? I seems that I can't use `mongodb` as a hostname.

Comment: @Hugo were you able to figure your query out?

Comment: @Shan-Desai hey - sorry it was a while ago - I really can't recall :/

Answer (score 1):

I am very convinced that @Yuriy Znatokov's answer is what I want, but I have understood it for a long time. In order to make it easier for later people to understand, I have exported the complete steps.

1) From inside the docker:dind container

```sh
docker run -d --name mydind --privileged docker:dind
/ # docker run -d -p 8080:80 httpd:alpine
/ # curl localhost:8080
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

2) From inside the docker:latest container

```sh
docker run -d --name mydind --privileged docker:dind
docker run -it --link mydind:docker docker:latest sh
/ # docker run -d -p 8080:80 httpd:alpine
/ # curl mydind:8080
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```